# pugixml - get all text nodes (PCDATA), not just the first

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

Currently, if I try to parse

```
<parent>
    First bit of text
    <child>
    </child>
    Second bit of text
</parent>
```

I only get `First bit of text` with

```
parent.text().get()
```

What's the correct way to grab all text nodes in `parent`?

1. Is there a nice utility function for this?
2. How could it be done iterating though all children?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no function that concatenates all text; if you want to get a list of text node children, you have two options:

1. XPath query:

   ```cpp
    pugi::xpath_node_set ns = parent.select_nodes("text()");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ns.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << ns[i].node().value() << std::endl;
   ```
2. Manual iteration w/type checking:

   ```cpp
    for (pugi::xml_node child = parent.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling())
        if (child.type() == pugi::node_pcdata)
            std::cout << child.value() << std::endl;
   ```

Note that if you can use C++11 then the second option can be much more concise:

```cpp
for (pugi::xml_node child: parent.children())
    if (child.type() == pugi::node_pcdata)
        std::cout << child.value() << std::endl;
```

(of course, you can also use ranged for to iterate through xpath_node_set)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I especially like the second method as it gives ordering with the other nodes, in case that's important to the application.

Answer (score -1):

In the version of pugixml I have, I can use the print method to get all the inner xml from a node into a stream. E.g.:
`std::stringstream ss;`
`node.print(ss);`
`return ss.str();`

Comment: Might want to elaborate on that. "The version I have" is useless to other readers. Provide it's number explicitly.